# How to find $c$ such that $\sum_{i=1}^{n} (|x_{i}-c|)$ is minimum for given $x_{i}$?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, optimization, maxima-minima

Suppose I have the function $f(c) =  \sum_{i=1}^{n} (|x_{i}-c|)$, where $x_{i}$ are given positive reals,  $1\leq i \leq n$, and $c$ is a real number. How could I find $c$ such that $f$ is minimum?

Edit - additionally, what about the case when $x_{i}$ are positive integers?

Comment: Your function is piecewise-smooth and convex.  Try to find points where the 1st order necessary optimality conditions are satisfied (they are also sufficient under convexity).  If there are none, check the points, where the function is non-differentiable: there are only $n$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a little more intuitive framed as a probability question.
Suppose the $x_i, i = 1, 2, ..., n$, are our given numbers, and let $X$ be a random variable which is uniformly distributed on the $x_i$, i.e. $$\Bbb{P}(X = x_i) = 1/n, \text{ for }i = 1, 2, ..., n.$$ Then minimizing $f(c) = \sum_{i=1}^n |x_i - c| \geq 0$ is equivalent to minimizing $$G(c) := \Bbb{E}|c - X| = \frac{f(c)}{n}.$$ Let's take the first derivative:
\begin{align*}
g(c) &:= G'(c) \\
&= \frac{d}{dc}\Bbb{E}|c - X| \\
&= \Bbb{E} \left[\frac{d}{dc}|c - X| \right] \\
&= \Bbb{E}\operatorname{sgn}(c - X), \
\end{align*}
where $\operatorname{sgn}$ is the [sign function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign_function). We can further calculate this last expectation as
\begin{align*}
g(c) &= \Bbb{E}\operatorname{sgn}(c - X) \\
&= \Bbb{E}[ \Bbb{1}_{c - X > 0} - \Bbb{1}_{c - X < 0}] \\
&= \Bbb{P}(c - X > 0) - \Bbb{P}(c - X < 0), \
\end{align*}
where $1_A$ is the indicator function of event $A$. Clearly, then, we have $g(c)$ is positive, negative, or zero according to whether $c$ is greater than, less than, or equal to the [median](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median) of $X$. That implies, by First Derivative Test, that $G(c)$ and $f(c)$ are minimized either when:

- $c = x_{(n+1)/2}$, if $n$ is odd; or
- $x_{n/2} < c < x_{(n/2 + 1)}$, if $n$ is even.